# how to redirect batch (cmd window) output into a VB form textbox1 or similar

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, cmd

So I have researched this for about 3 days now and everything that I find doesn't work or throws 10+ Errors. I am trying take the output from a batch file (CMD Window that shows generated strings) and insert it into TextBox1 on my VB Form1. So when I push the button, the batch is executed which opens up (on toolbar) a CMD window, shows the strings as they are produced while being inserted into what might be an open file dialog but for now its textbox1. Is there a way to do this and/or is this where create pipeline comes in? I apologize in advance I am a week old beginner. Below is what I have for button1 and textbox1. I get one error  TxtResults.txt. What am I missing or doing wrong please?

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("C:\Test.bat")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim myprocess As New Process
    Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    StartInfo.FileName = "cmd" 'starts cmd window
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'required to redirect
    StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True '<---- creates no window, obviously
    myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
    myprocess.Start()
    Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
    Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
    SW.WriteLine(TextBox1) 'the command you wish to run.....
    SW.WriteLine("exit") 'exits command prompt window
    txtResults.Text = SR.ReadToEnd 'returns results of the command window
    SW.Close()
    SR.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: So you have changed completely your code copying my answer. This will give no context to anyone reading this question, but at least let us know if this works or not and it if doesn't work what is the error that you receive.

Comment: I changed it back. Hope I didn't confuse anyone. And not it did not work. Back to the original code. Is it even remotely close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute your batch file in the button click, not on the textchanged event.
As an example I have created a simple batch file that executes just the command `DIR /A /B`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
    Dim psi = new ProcessStartInfo() With 
    {
            .WorkingDirectory = "D:\temp",
            .FileName = "d:\temp\dirlist.cmd", 
            .CreateNoWindow = true,
            .RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            .RedirectStandardInput = true,
            .UseShellExecute = false
    }
    Dim pSpawn = new Process()
    pSpawn.StartInfo = psi
    AddHandler pSpawn.OutputDataReceived, Function(sender, args) sb.AppendLine(args.Data)
    pSpawn.Start()
    pSpawn.BeginOutputReadLine()
    pSpawn.WaitForExit()
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub
```

If you want the output from the batch file go directly to the textbox you could change the AddHandler call with

```
AddHandler pSpawn.OutputDataReceived, Function(sender, args) 
    TextBox1.Text.AppendText(args.Data & Environment.NewLine)
    return 0
End Function
```

And remove both the StringBuilder and the final assignment to the TextBox

Comment: Forgive my obvious lack of knowledge here, but like this? oh it doesnt let me post code in a comment.